# md5pass or sha1pass on mac os

Tags: macos, shell, md5, hashing, sha1

I'm looking for a hash tool on MacOS (shell), hope it works like md5pass on Ubuntu.

1. Calculate case sensitive hash code.
2. Calculate salted hash code.
3. md5 is good, any other algorithm is ok.

I installed md5sha1sum package by Mac ports, but still can't find md5pass command. There is a md5sum tool now, can I use that do what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `openssl`?

e.g. `$ echo "string+salt" | openssl sha1`

`openssl` also includes a `passwd` mode to generate hashed and salted `/etc/shadow` and Apache style passwords in MD5 and SHA-1. Check the man page.

[MD5 is not recommended any more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security).

Comment: Thanks for your advice @rjocoleman. I tried openssl, but still don't know how to get a case sensitive hash code.

Comment: what do you mean case sensitive, I see that behaviour as standard?  `$ echo "string+salt" | openssl sha1  
55efabfbf6b4fd62ac5e25aebc0b2598e5fbf1c7`  

`$ echo "String+salt" | openssl sha1  
7c5f8364f964e0aa91db6418b2a21d237f9d34b1`

Comment: Yes, by this way, the result you get are all numbers and lower case alphabet, but sha1pass tool output like this:   

$4$salt$mHXK36+Tx47/8wN43QVM+aX0pyM$

Comment: in last example, $4 means sha1 algorithm, $salt is the salt content, rest part is the hash result

Comment: Gotcha. So going back to MD5 for a second `$ openssl passwd -1 -salt salt password` but that's MD5.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you very much! :)